# Swift Package Dependency on local package using relative file path

Tags: swift, xcode, path, swift-package-manager

Using Xcode `File/Swift Packages/Add Package Dependency` menu option I am able to add a local package by giving the url as *file:///Users/saran/Desktop/Temp/NetworkUtility*

Since it takes absolute path in my machine, would affect team development when a team member checkout my commit.

Is there a way I can mention the file url as relative path to the depending local package.

Having my consuming app in a folder sibling to NetworkUtility
I tried `file://$(SRCROOT)/../NetworkUtility`, but only getting popup "An unknown error occurred"

Not sure from which directory it is trying to resolve.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly, but what would change using relative path, it is still on your computer - your team will note have package there either after checkout.

Comment: If its relative to `$(SRCROOT)` then it can be committed along with the rest of the project so the team would have access after checkout

Comment: You need 3 `/` i.e. file:///XXXXXX